# How to create a table in a particular Postgres schema with Sequel gem?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sequel

I'm new to Sequel and just started exploring it. I was able to create a new schema:

```
DB = Sequel.postgres('some_db')
DB.create_schema(:some_schema, if_not_exists: true)
```

I verified, that the schema was created. However, I can't find a way to create a table in the newly created schema. I couldn't find documentation explaining this and I tried, but couldn't succeed, with:

```
DB.create_table(:some_table, schema: 'some_schema')
DB.create_table('some_schema.some_table')
DB.create_table(:some_schema__some_table)
```

Every time, it creates the table in the `public` schema. What is the way to create the table in the `some_schema` schema?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By reading some answers to some old questions, I managed to create the table in the following way:

```
DB.create_table(Sequel[:some_schema][:some_table])
```

I wonder if this is the "official" way of doing this and if this is documented somewhere.

Answer from the author of Sequel:

There are many ways, see:

http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/README_rdoc.html#label-Qualifying+identifiers+-28column-2Ftable+names-29

http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/sql_rdoc.html#label-Identifiers