# Access Postgresql Schema with Sequel Gem

Tags: sequel

I am trying to access a certain schema in my postgresql database.

Found this related question:

[How to create a table in a particular Postgres schema with Sequel gem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52870539/how-to-create-a-table-in-a-particular-postgres-schema-with-sequel-gem)

And it also references in the docs:

https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel#label-Qualifying+identifiers+-28column-2Ftable+names-29

But when running it always qualifies the first symbol as the table and the second as the column:

```
Sequel[:schema][:table]
=> #<Sequel::SQL::QualifiedIdentifier @table=>"schema", @column=>:table>
```

And when I use three symbols the third is qualified as a second column:

```
Sequel[:schema][:table][:column]
=> #<Sequel::SQL::QualifiedIdentifier @table=>#<Sequel::SQL::QualifiedIdentifier @table=>"schema", @column=>:table>, @column=>:column>
```

Not sure what I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some work arounds on this question:

[How to INSERT in a table that is in a Postgres schema with Sequel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76331104/how-to-insert-in-a-table-that-is-in-a-postgres-schema-with-sequel)

Here the two the I used:

```
DB.from{schema[:table]} # SELECT * FROM schema.table
```

and

```
DB = Sequel.connect(adapter, host, database, search_path: "some_schema", user, password)
```